# Почему не выводит данные с bd TbGridView в yii1?

Tags: php, yii, виджет

Cам виджет

```
$modelMahala = new RefMahala();
    $dataProvider = $modelMahala->search();
    if($dataProvider != null){
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'id'=>'vacancies-grid',
            'type'=>'striped',
            'ajaxUpdate' => true,
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'template' => '{items}{pager}',
            'columns'=>array(
                array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'№', 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 0px'),),
                'name::'.Yii::t('mahala','Махаля'),
                array(
                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    'template'=>'{myview}',
                    'buttons'=>array(
                        'myview'=>array(
                            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("tools/mahala", array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                            'label' => Yii::t('service','Просмотр'),
                            'options'=>array('class' => 'btn', 'style' => 'width:150px;'),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                        'style'=>'width:100px;',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

Сама модель

```
public function search()
{

$language = Yii::app()->language;
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
$criteria->compare('district_id',$this->district_id);
$criteria->compare('name_ru',$this->name_ru,true);
$criteria->compare('name_uz',$this->name_uz,true);
$criteria->compare('name_en',$this->name_en,true);
$criteria->compare('address_ru',$this->address_ru,true);
$criteria->compare('address_uz',$this->address_uz,true);
$criteria->compare('address_en',$this->address_en,true);
$criteria->compare('sort',$this->sort);
$criteria->compare('active',$this->active);

$criteria->select = 'id, name_'.$language.' AS "name"';

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
  'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
}
```

`id` выводит, а вот `name` не выводит. Подскажите, почему?
первый раз ошибся не из той модели подгрузил имена но они подгрузились, а вот с другой модели не хотят хотя название полей в таблицы идентичны с которой первой грузил.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить атрибут в модель:

```
public $name;
```

Руководства говорит по этому поводу следующее http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.ar

> Каждый класс AR отражает таблицу (или
>   представление) базы данных, экземпляр AR — строку в этой таблице.
>
> Значения полей в строке таблицы доступны как атрибуты соответствующего
>   экземпляра AR-класса. Например, код ниже устанавливает значение для
>   атрибута title:

```
$post=new Post;
$post->title='тестовая запись';
```

> Хотя мы никогда не объявляем заранее свойство title класса Post, мы,
>   тем не менее, можем обратиться к нему как в коде выше. Это возможно
>   потому, что title является полем таблицы tbl_post, и CActiveRecord
>   делает его доступным в качестве свойства благодаря магическому методу
>   PHP __get(). Если аналогичным образом обратиться к несуществующему
>   полю, будет выброшено исключение.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?